# How to pick a class with the same name. (Instagram Selenium BOT)

Tags: python, class, selenium, xpath

My Problem:

```
while i <= 10:

victimname = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//a[@class="FPmhX notranslate zsYNt "]')

victimname.click()

time.sleep(1)

content = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="-vDIg"]')

f = open("snapchat.txt", "w") 

f.write(content.text)

f.close()

browser.back()

i += 1
```

After one loop I want to change the **victimname** in the second li element of the list.

I hope the IMG helps.

[image]

Comment: `for element in browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//a[@class="FPmhX notranslate zsYNt "]'): element.click()`

Comment: What do you mean by all in one row? Please post sample html for which you are trying to make it work

Comment: I have updated my question.

Comment: you have url in that class so u can use url of that class

Comment: The URL always change, i can't take this tag

Comment: why don't you use browser.find_elements and retrieve each element via for loop

Comment: The only tag i can use is class and the class of these two listings are the same. :/

Comment: Yes exactly, use browser.find_elements_by_class_name

Comment: Yeah. But with this xPath i only grab the first class but after the loop i want to grab the second class with the same name.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code :

```
wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 30)  

first_button = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//div[text()='Mohammedsharshar']/preceding-sibling::div/a')))  
first_button.click()  

# your action after first click 
second_button = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//div[contains(text(),'Samar Khan')]/preceding-sibling::div/a')))  
second_button .click()
```

make sure you are importing :

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

You can use these two css selector also , if the above xpath did not work :

**first button** :  `(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'a[title='mohamedsharshar10']')`

**second button** : `(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'a[title='samarkhan2842']')`

Comment: Thx for this fast answer. The problem is the title change when I reload the page. The only thing that did not change is the class tag.

Comment: See I believe those are name , you already know which name you are going to add , so store that name in a variable like first_name = Mohammad

Comment: and use xpath like :  //div[text()='"+first_name+"']/preceding-sibling::div/a   ,  this will be a dynamic way to handle the scenario.

Comment: I have given an alternative for the same in comment section , that xpath takes name. And for provided name you can click it easily.

Comment: I understand, but I don´t have a name. The name is always a different.

Comment: From some where you must be taking the names ? Or how the names gets generated ?

Comment: You saw the IMG in my updated Question. It´s a list of Instagram Followers these list is always changing. :/

Comment: Is it desktop version of instagram ? Then I can have a real look

Comment: Yes it's the desktop version. :)